# INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChangedEventHandler event is always null

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, delegates, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to the following class

```
 public class FactoryItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        string symbol;
        public string Symbol
        {
            get { return symbol; }
            set { symbol = value; OnPropertyChanged("Symbol"); }
        }

        public FactoryItems()
        {

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

When the Symbol property changes the event fires with no problems but the PropertyChanged event is always null, this class gets instantiated once only, I placed a breakpoint on the constructor to make sure its the case.

In another class this is how I subscribe to it:

```
Data.Tables.FactoryItems = new Data.FactoryItems();
Data.Tables.FactoryItems.PropertyChanged += 
new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(FactoryItems_SymbolChanged);

void FactoryItems_SymbolChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  doSomething();
}
```

But the handler is always null as PropertyChanged is null. Any idea how to get this working?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your code looks OK, I would try `Data.Tables.FactoryItems.Symbol = "test";` right after the `+=` line. With a Debugger active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're subscribing to the event on one particular instance.
That doesn't affect any other instances.

To see changes for all instances, you can use a static event.
Beware that any class that subscribes to the static event will stay in memory forever.

Comment: Hi @Slaks would you be able to provide me a short example on how to do that for the code above?

Answer (score 3):

Until someone subscribes to the event, it will remain `null`.

Comment: @devdigital @marc-gravell I have updated the code to show the subscription bit, I'm not using WPF or XAML, its just a class in the business layer that needs to advise a method of the FactoryItem static "table" changes in order to run another method to get updates from another source.

Answer (score 1):

There are various types that will subscribe to this - most notably thing like `DataGridView` (winforms, but similar in WPF etc) but **only** when data-bound (set `DataSource`), and **only** if the list *also* supports binding - for example `BindingList<T>`.

To test, simply subscribe to if yourself with `PropertyChanged += ...`.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I was binding to a Linq enumerable of anonymous type and could not for the life of me figure out why it wasn't binding to my `Combobox` `ItemsSource`. I forgot the `.ToList()` on the end. Took me so long u_u

Answer (score 0):

Are you just setting the `Symbol` property value in code and debugging from there?  In which case, nothing may have subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event.

If you are doing XAML development, then try setting the `DataContext` for a XAML element to be an instance of your `FactoryItems` type, and then bind the `Symbol` property to a `Text` property on a TextBox (for example), and you will find the XAML binding engine has subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event, so it won't be null.

Alternatively, just have another type manually subscribe to your `FactoryItems` `PropertyChanged` event to test things in code.